# Area of Region using Transformation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, transformation

Let R be the region bounded by the curves x = 0, y = sin(x)+1, y = sin(x),
and y = 2 − x. Find the area of R.

I need to use a transformation to find this, but I could not solve it using a transformation to a rectangle. How else, then could I evaluate it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: The R region is bounded by the red, green, and blue curves]

The R region is bounded by the red, green, and blue curves. Calculate first the intersections of y=2-x with the two sin curves, and you can write your integral as the sum of two parts.

Comment: Why would you calculate it as the sum of two parts, when there is only one region bounded by all 4 curves?

Comment: Say the intersection of the red curve with y=sin(x)+1 is at $(x_0,y_0)$. The region between x=0 and x=$x_0$ has the area $x_0$ (integrate the difference between the two curves between 0 and $x_0$. For the second intersection, with sin(x) at $(x_1,y_1)$, the area is given by integrating (2-x-sin(x)) between $x_0$ and $x_1$